# Template specialization doesn't see a function in its point of instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, instantiation

I don't understand why it isn't correct

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct CL{};

template <typename T>
void fnc(T t)
{
    f(t);
}

namespace NS {
    void f(CL){}
    void fn() {fnc(CL()); /*error is here*/}
    //point of instantiation fnc<CL> is here (in namespace scope,
    //according to 14.6.4.1/1)
}

int main(){}
```

Calling `f(t)` in template function `fnc` is dependent on template parameter and then name lookup must be at an instantiation point. I saw Standard (C++ 14) 14.6.4.1/1

> For a function template specialization, a member function template
>   specialization, or a specialization for a member function or static
>   data member of a class template, if the specialization is implicitly
>   instantiated because it is referenced from within another template
>   specialization and the context from which it is referenced depends
>   on a template parameter, the point of instantiation of the
>   specialization is the point of instantiation of the enclosing
>   specialization. **Otherwise, the point of instantiation for such a
>   specialization immediately follows the namespace scope declaration or
>   definition that refers to the specialization.**

`f(CL)` is visible at a point of instantiation of `fnc<CL>`, but all the compilers (VS, gcc, clang) give an error. What is reason for that behavior?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here the argument `t` of `fnc` is a dependent name, which cannot be resolved when parsing templates. Instead, they are looked up again at the point of instantiation. This is so-called two-phase lookup: the 1st phase is the parsing of a template, and the 2nd phase is its instantiation.

The answer to your question lies in the fact that the 2nd lookup performed at the POI (point of instantiation) is only an **ADL**. Because the struct `CL` is not defined inside the same namespace with `void f(CL)`, the POI lookup would therefore not take place and would not find it.

If you try to put the definition of the struct `CL` into the namespace to make [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) take effect, it will compile well.

```
namespace NS {
    struct CL{};
    void f(CL){}
    //...
}
```

According to the rule of [unqualified name lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup), (bold by me)

> For a dependent name used in a template definition, the lookup is
>   postponed until the template arguments are known, at which time ADL
>   examines function declarations with external linkage (until C++11)
>   that are visible from the template definition context as well as in
>   the template instantiation context, while non-ADL lookup only examines
>   function declarations with external linkage (until C++11) that are
>   visible from the template definition context (in other words, **adding
>   a new function declaration after template definition does not make it
>   visible except via ADL**).

Comment: Thanks, but now I don't understand what 14.6.4.1/1 means. How it differs from 14.7.1?